# Angular trying to pass parameter to a service

Tags: angularjs

Trying to pass a parameter to a service like this

```
.service('modalService', ['$modal','$log', function ($modal,$log) {
    'use strict';


    this.showcodeModal = function(testing) {
      $log.warn("gets here");
      $log.warn(testing);
      $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/modal/showcode.html',
        controller: 'showcodeCtrl',
        windowClass: 'code-result',
        resolve: {
          address: function () {
            return 'test variable';
          }
        }
      });
    };
}])
```

But always returns "undefined" for my parameter "testing".

And it's called from my controller like this

```
 var test = "test";
 modalService.showcodeModal(test);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have `modalService.showcodeModal()` somewhere else and that's the one that is firing? That's the only way I can think this could happen.

Comment: does "gets here" print out? what about just a regular `console.log(testing)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works fine. Formatted a bit differently, if that helps.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','myService',
    function ($scope,myService) {

      myService.showcodeModal('testing');

    }]);


myApp.service("myService",["$http",
    function($http) {

      return {

        showcodeModal:function(aval) {

         console.log(aval);
        }


        };

}]);
```